# JPA timestamp comparison not working

Tags: java, jpa, hsqldb

I have a persistent object with two `Date` fields, like this

```
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
private Date generated;

@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
private Date expirationTime;
```

On object construction the `expirationTime` is initialized based on the `generated` field

```
this.expirationTime = new Date(generated.getTime() + ttlMillis);
```

Now I'm trying to delete all expired objects from the database with a JPA query

```
Query q = em.createQuery("delete from MyObject t where CURRENT_TIMESTAMP > t.expirationTime");
q.executeUpdate();
```

But running a simple test

```
MyObject o = new MyObject(somePastDate, someTTL);
em.persist(o);
... create the query above
q.executeUpate();
```

shows no row is being deleted. Any clue on what I'm doing wrong? I'm running tests on HSQLDb and using Hibernate as my JPA provider.

**Edit**: solved, but I'm not sure why this version should work differently.

```
Query q = em.createQuery("delete from MyObject t where :now > t.expirationTime");
q.setParameter("now", new Date());
q.executeUpdate();
```

What's the use of `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` if comparisons with other fields fail?

Comment: You can set the hibernate property - `show_sql` to `true`, to see the query generated by hibernate.

Comment: Instead of editing your question with the answer, you should post it as an actual answer and accept it. This way the question will be marked as answered, which it actually is.

Answer (score 0):

You did not set any parameter, and the query has to get a named parameter:

```
Query q = em.createQuery("delete from MyObject t where CURRENT_TIMESTAMP > :expirationTime");
q.setParameter("expirationTime" , yourObject.getExpirationTime());//or your getter
q.executeUpdate();
```

I add a link to enforce the topic [here](http://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/query/parameter).

Check if it works :-)

Comment: I don't think I need a parameter, `expirationTime` is a member of the persistent object. Checking the link.